# New window replicates

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I am working on an interface that uses a Wcf to obtain data from out database, I am having the following issue, I am using a dynamic window to display information as well as some buttons for date times, and close, etc...

However when I close the window and reopen it, it adds everything back to the form that was already there, which creates double and is causing some problems, any advice would be great, thanks in advance

Here is some code to better describe what I have....

This is the button I have on my primary form, which creates the new window

```
private void butMoreInf_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    winMain.DataContext = null;
    winMainContainer.DataContext = null;
    winMainContainerLeft.DataContext = null;
    winMainContainerRight.DataContext = null;
    datGrid.DataContext = null;

    //Generate the new window and panel to go within the window
    winMain.Height = 750;
    winMain.Width = 950;
    winMainContainer.Width = 1000;
    winMainContainer.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
    winMainContainerLeft.Width = 120;
    winMainContainerLeft.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
    winMainContainerRight.Width = 880;
    winMainContainerRight.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;

    //Generate the datagrid to contain the date to be changed etc.
    datGrid.Margin = new Thickness(0, 12, 12, 12);
    datGrid.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Right;

    //Generate a datepicker (start) and label
    Label labS = new Label();
    labS.Content = "Pick a start date";
    labS.Width = 100;
    labS.Margin = new Thickness(12, 1, 0, 1);
    labS.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;

    DatePicker datPickStart = new DatePicker();
    datPickStart.Width = 100;
    datPickStart.Margin = new Thickness(12, 12, 1, 0);
    datPickStart.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
    datPickStart.SelectedDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7);
    datStartPick = datPickStart.SelectedDate == null ? DateTime.Now : Convert.ToDateTime(datPickStart.SelectedDate);

    //Generate a datepicker (end) and label
    Label labE = new Label();
    labE.Content = "Pick an end date";
    labE.Width = 100;
    labE.Margin = new Thickness(12, 1, 0, 1);
    labE.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;

    DatePicker datPickEnd = new DatePicker();
    datPickEnd.Width = 100;
    datPickEnd.Margin = new Thickness(12, 12, 1, 0);
    datPickEnd.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
    datPickEnd.SelectedDate = DateTime.Now;
    datEndPick = datPickEnd.SelectedDate == null ? DateTime.Now : Convert.ToDateTime(datPickEnd.SelectedDate);

    //Generate dropdown and label for that box
    Label labY = new Label();
    labY.Content = "";
    labY.Width = 100;
    labY.Margin = new Thickness(12, 1, 0, 1);
    labY.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;

    ComboBox txtY = new ComboBox();
    txtY.Width = 100;
    txtY.Margin = new Thickness(12, 12, 1, 0);
    txtY.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
    txtY.SelectedIndex = 0;
    txtY.SelectionChanged += CLLoadErrors;

    txtY.SelectedIndex = 0;

    //Generate error list button
    Button butError = new Button();
    butError.Width = 100;
    butError.Margin = new Thickness(12, 12, 1, 0);
    butError.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
    butError.Content = "Get Errors";
    butError.Click += CLLoadErrors;

    //Generate clear button
    Button butClear = new Button();
    butClear.Width = 100;
    butClear.Margin = new Thickness(12, 12, 1, 0);
    butClear.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
    butClear.Content = "Clear Grid";
    butClear.Click += clearDataGrid;

    //Generate close button
    Button butClose = new Button();
    butClose.Width = 100;
    butClose.Margin = new Thickness(12, 12, 1, 0);
    butClose.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
    butClose.Content = "Close";
    butClose.Click += CLHide;

    //Add elements to the stackpanel / Also updates them before each instance
    winMainContainerLeft.UpdateLayout();

    winMainContainerLeft.Children.Add(labS);
    winMainContainerLeft.Children.Add(datPickStart);
    winMainContainerLeft.Children.Add(labE);
    winMainContainerLeft.Children.Add(datPickEnd);
    winMainContainerLeft.Children.Add(labY);
    winMainContainerLeft.Children.Add(txtY);
    winMainContainerLeft.Children.Add(butError);
    winMainContainerLeft.Children.Add(butClear);
    winMainContainerLeft.Children.Add(butClose);

    winMainContainerRight.UpdateLayout();
    winMainContainerRight.Children.Remove(datGrid);
    winMainContainerRight.Children.Add(datGrid);

    winMainContainer.UpdateLayout();
    winMainContainer.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;
    winMainContainer.Children.Remove(winMainContainerLeft);
    winMainContainer.Children.Add(winMainContainerLeft);
    winMainContainer.Children.Remove(winMainContainerRight);
    winMainContainer.Children.Add(winMainContainerRight);

    winMain.ResizeMode = ResizeMode.NoResize;

    //Display the new form
    winMain.UpdateLayout();
    winMain.Content = winMainContainer;
    winMain.Show();

    datGrid.MouseDoubleClick += datGridDClick;
    txtY.SelectionChanged += new SelectionChangedEventHandler(txtY_SelectionChanged);
}
```

Will provide more code if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reusing the same window again and again (why?), so you need to clear out the children collections before you add new elements, otherwise every click on your button will show the window + every control you add, resulting in double/triple/... controls.

Update: I assume you use `StackPanels` (from your comment / having `Children` enumerations). The `Children` enumeration is a [UIElementCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.uielementcollection.aspx) which allows to invoke the `Clear` method. Just call this prior to adding new controls. (on `winMainContainer`, `winMainContainerRight` and `winMainContainerLeft`)

Comment: That is why I have nulled out the datacontexts. I also tried to remove the children elements and rebuild them, but seemed to have the same issue

Comment: Setting the datacontext to `null` has no influence on the controls collections itself. You can't remove the children elements by calling `ComboBox xy = new ComboBox(); ...; winMainContainerLeft.Children.Remove(xy);` because it has another referene value.

Comment: Ok that makes more sense, Let me try that out

Answer (score 0):

Where do you initialize winMain? Is it a static variable or does it live within your current form? 
I'm guessing that you keep adding controls to an existing object(which causes the duplication effect). To fix this you could either reinitialize the form object

```
winMain = new WinMainForm();
```

or you could remove all controls on the winMain variable right before adding the new children

```
foreach(var c in winMainContainer.children){
  winMainContainer.children.remove(c)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you aren't creating a new window at all, rather just performing operations on 'winMain' which exists at some higher scope.  So every time you call the function you are just adding more and more children to the stackpanel.

You can solve the problem by doing something like this in the beginning of your method.

```
winMainContainerLeft.Clear();
winMainContainerRight.Clear();
winMainContainer.Children.Clear();
```

I also noticed that you have included the following lines in your example:

```
winMainContainer.Children.Remove(winMainContainerLeft);
winMainContainer.Children.Add(winMainContainerLeft);
winMainContainer.Children.Remove(winMainContainerRight);
winMainContainer.Children.Add(winMainContainerRight);
```

But you don't need to remove them before adding them (this doesn't really make sense anyway.)

Comment: Was just a theory I was trying.. C# is not my trump card, thank you